# XML DOM xml Property in IE10?

Tags: xml, internet-explorer-10, xmldom

There seems to be a problem with Internet Explorer 10 Release Preview. I don't know if this is a bug, or Microsoft has decided to remove the property XML DOM.

Test:
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_attr_xml

Result in Internet Explorer 10 Release Preview:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Result in Internet Explorer 10 Consumer Preview and earlier:

```
category="cooking"
category="children"
category="web"
category="web"
```

Answer (score 0):

They have changed the behavior in the latest release http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/07/19/xmlhttprequest-responsexml-in-ie10-release-preview.aspx

Who knows what other surprises will come with the final release?